# Get TableviewCells to display different data that is extracted from firebase and show them in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this two structs, the data I am getting from a `Firebase Database` and I don't know how to get each tableview cell to display a different collection view, I have both cells (TableviewCell and CollectionViewCell) in xib Files but can't get them the way I want it to.

I have attached my `ViewController` where they are both in and the TableViewCell class. Please help

```
struct Clothes {
var price: Double
var imgClUrl: String
var id: String
var isActive: Bool = true
var timeStamp: Timestamp
var stock: Double
var name: String
init(data : [String : Any]) {
    self.price = data["price"] as? Double ?? 0
    self.imgClUrl = data["imgClUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    self.id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
    self.isActive = data["isActive"] as? Bool ?? true
    self.timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
    self.stock = data["stock"] as? Double ?? 0
    self.name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

}

```
struct TypesOfCLothing {
var title : String
var id : String
var clothes : [Clothes]
init (data : [String : Any]){
    self.title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
    self.id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
    self.clothes = data["Clothes"] as! [Clothes]
}
```

}

```
class eachStoreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var eachRowCollView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var eachRowLbl: UILabel!


var clothes = [Clothes]()
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


    eachRowCollView?.reloadData()
    eachRowCollView?.delegate = self
    eachRowCollView?.dataSource = self
    self.eachRowCollView?.register(UINib(nibName: "RowColectionView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothesCell)
}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func configureCell(clothingType: TypesOfCLothing) {
    eachRowLbl?.text = clothingType.title}}
extension eachStoreTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return clothes.count
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothesCell, for: indexPath) as? RowColectionView{
        cell.configureCell(clothes: clothes[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: 180)
}


class EachStoreVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var StoreTblView: UITableView!

 var typesOfClothing = [TypesOfCLothing]()

var tienda: Tiendas!
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var listener : ListenerRegistration!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  // StoreTblView?.delegate = self
   // StoreTblView?.dataSource = self
            StoreTblView?.register(UINib(nibName: "eachStoreTblViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothingTypeCell)
            StoreTblView?.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}}


extension EachStoreVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return typesOfClothing.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothingTypeCell, for: indexPath) as? eachStoreTableViewCell {
        cell.configureCell(clothingType: typesOfClothing[indexPath.row])
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: StoreTblView.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height)
        return cell
        }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 200
 }}
```

EDIT 
The collectionView and Tableview now show fine but I'm having trouble getting the data from firebase, I have an array of document references inside each TypesOfClothing document, the code is as follows. I have also updated my 2 Structs.

```
    func getRowData(){
   listener = db.collection("TypesOfClothing").addSnapshotListener({ (snap, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        snap?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
            let data = change.document.data()
            let typesOfClothing = TypesOfCLothing.init(data: data)

            switch change.type {
                case.added:
                    self.onDocumentAdded(change: change, category: typesOfClothing)
                case.modified:
                    self.onDocumentModified(change: change, category: typesOfClothing)
                case.removed:
                    self.onDocumentRemoved(change: change)

            }
        })

    })    }


func onDocumentAdded(change: DocumentChange, category: TypesOfCLothing){
    let newIndex = Int(change.newIndex)
    typesOfClothing.insert(category, at: newIndex)
    StoreTblView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: newIndex, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.left)

}
func onDocumentModified(change: DocumentChange, category: TypesOfCLothing){
    if change.newIndex == change.oldIndex {
        let index = Int(change.newIndex)
        typesOfClothing[index] = category
        StoreTblView?.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.left)

    } else {
        let oldIndex = Int(change.oldIndex)
        let newIndex = Int(change.newIndex)
        typesOfClothing.remove(at: oldIndex)
        typesOfClothing.insert(category, at: newIndex)

        StoreTblView?.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: oldIndex, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: newIndex, section: 0))
    }
}
func onDocumentRemoved(change: DocumentChange){
    let oldIndex = Int(change.oldIndex)
    typesOfClothing.remove(at: Int(oldIndex))
    StoreTblView?.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: oldIndex, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.fade)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct use like this:

```
struct TypesOfClothing {
   var title : String
   var clothes: [Clothes]

}

struct Clothes {
 var price: Double
 var imgClUrl: String
 var id: String
 var isActive: Bool = true
 var timeStamp: Timestamp
 var stock: Double
 var name: String
}
```

in Main View controller: try code like this:

```
var typesOfClothing: [TypesOfClothing] = []
```

in numberOfRowsInSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return typesOfClothing.count
}
```

in cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothingTypeCell, for: indexPath) as? eachStoreTableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row < typesOfClothing?.count ?? 0 {
           let cellData = typesOfClothing?[indexPath.row]

           cell.configureCell(cellData)
        }
       return cell
    }        
    return UITableViewCell()
  }
```

in UITableViewCell class try like this:

```
class eachStoreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

   @IBOutlet weak var eachRowCollView: UICollectionView!

   @IBOutlet weak var eachRowLbl: UILabel!


   var clothes = [Clothes]()
   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

       eachRowCollView?.delegate = self
       eachRowCollView?.dataSource = self
       self.eachRowCollView?.register(UINib(nibName: "RowColectionView", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothesCell)
       }
       override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
       }

       func configureCell(_ clothingType: TypesOfClothing) {
        eachRowLbl?.text = clothingType.title
        clothes = clothingType.clothes 
        eachRowCollView?.reloadData()
         }
     }

   extension eachStoreTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return clothes.count
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothesCell, for: indexPath) as? RowColectionView{
    cell.configureCell(clothes: clothes[indexPath.item])
    return cell
    }
     return UICollectionViewCell()
 }
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: 160, height: 180)
      }
  }
```

it'll help you.

Comment: Why `if indexPath.row < typesOfClothing?.count ?? 0 {` is needed?

Comment: For checking if clothes data less than means it'll not display and prevent from array index out of bound also

Comment: You have used `typesOfClothing.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. So above check is meaningless

Comment: Also `typesOfClothing` is non optional array. Optional chaining like `typesOfClothing?.count` will throw an error

Comment: Well if the data in that array will be changing frequently, its always safer to check for index out of bound. Incase your array will be stable and wont change much, then you may ignore that line.

Comment: So in my firestore database(in the “TypesOfClothing” group)should i create an array called clothes that contains the id for all of the clothes i want inside that tableview cell?

Comment: Yes you can create an array of any structure in firebase database... based on that you can create your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one structs for load tableView Data

```
struct ClothingData
{
   var typesOfClothing : String = ""
   var clothes : [Clothes] = []
}
```

Load this structArray for tabelView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return ClothingData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.ClothingTypeCell, for: indexPath) as? eachStoreTableViewCell

    let row = ClothingData[indexPath.row]

    cell.eachRowLbl?.text = row.typesOfClothing
    cell.clothes = row.clothes
    // Here you can pass clothesList to tabelViewCell for load collectionView
    return cell
}
```